# How to compare column values of different rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the requirement where I need to check different rows of same column (S_ALR_date) in sql. If EntryDate should be in between S_ALR_date or greater that S_ALR_date for same G/L acct and user name then that is exception which have to show in output.

I am unable to compare the different rows of same table as Entry date should be between S_ALR_date or greater than S_ALR_date.

Below is my table:

```
G/L acct    User name     S_ALR_date            EntryDate

44444       USER_FV70   17-04-2014 04:46    17-04-2014 05:52
113100      RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:12    04-03-2014 12:44
113100      RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:35    04-03-2014 12:44
113100      RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:35    04-03-2014 12:49
113100      RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:45    04-03-2014 12:49
113100      RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:12    04-03-2014 12:49
113190      ADMIN       01-02-2014 06:50    03-02-2014 07:00
```

output should be like this:

```
G/L acct    User name   S_ALR_date            EntryDate

44444      USER_FV70   17-04-2014 04:46    17-04-2014 05:52
113100     RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:35    04-03-2014 12:44
113100     RAMLAPR     04-03-2014 12:45    04-03-2014 12:49
113190     ADMIN       01-02-2014 06:50    03-02-2014 07:00
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic more clearly?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I want to highlight those records where Entry date is in between two occurances of S_ALR_date or greater than S_ALR_date i.e. Entrydate 04-03-2014 12:44 is in between 04-03-2014 12: 35 and  04-03-2014 12: 45 hence this should be highlighted for same G/L acct and User name